# ActivatedRoute set as undefined in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to read passed parameters while navigating in angular2 using **ActivatedRoute** but when I try `this.route.params` I am getting `this.route` as **undefined**. Here is my code for Description component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "angular2/router";
import {LocalStorageService} from "app/common/services/data/localStorageService";

@Component({
    selector: "description",
    template: `
        {{ data.name }}
    `,
    providers: [LocalStorageService]
})

export class Description implements OnInit {

    data: Object;

    constructor(private service: LocalStorageService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            this.data = this.service.getInformation(params["name"]);
        });
    }
}
```

I have declared routes using `RouteConfig`

```
@RouteConfig([{
    path: "",
    component: Dashboard,
    name: "Dashboard"
}, {
    path: "/:name",
    component: Description,
    name: "Description"
}])
```

and I am navigating using below code

```
onCardClick(item) {
    this.router.navigate(["Description", {
        name: item.name
    }]);
}
```

I have tried adding **ActivatedRoute** inside providers but that doesn't seems to help. At code execution I get this error

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
    at new Description 
(http://localhost:3000/app/pages/description/components/Description.js:27:43)
    at AppView._View_Description_Host0.createInternal (Description_Host.template.js:15:32)
    at AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2.dev.js:23468:23)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2.dev.js:7673:34)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2.dev.js:5763:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2.dev.js:4147:25
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:349:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2.dev.js:2189:31)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:348:35)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:242:44)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Comment: What's exactly the error message? If `this.route` was null than Angular's DI would throw an exception that the service `ActivatedRoute` doesn't exist I think.

Comment: i have updated the error. It doesn't say anything about `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: so where's the line that causes the error?

Comment: it is this `this.route.params.forEach((params: Params)`. Ignore the line numbers from stack trace as I quickly added the code again to reproduce the error and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be an older version of angular2.  The following works in the context of Angular 2.1.0.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let name = this.route.snapshot.params["name"];
}
```

Comment: I am using angular beta version so that might be the reason. let me try to update all my dependencies to angular 2.1.0 and try again.

Comment: take this as an opportunity to use angular-cli.  sets it all up in a jiffy wrapped in a bow

Answer (score 0):

the import sentences 'angular2/core' should be '@angular/core' .

Comment: there is no problem with that. I am able to run my application just fine. The problem is that I am not able to read parameters that I am passing during navigation. for starters I referred to http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/07/angular-2.html and was trying to create a basic app of my own